# When we change scale of image then what is effect on image in javafx 2.x?

Tags: javafx, javafx-2

When we change scale of image then translate X and Y are same, Layout X and Y both are also same. Width and height of image are same. Then what is change in image or imageView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

scaleXProperty and scaleYProperty in ImageView. (And scaleZProperty if that's the case). Since they are DoubleProperty objects you can even bind custom events on them!!